# convert HTML5 Regex pattern to javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, html, validation

For an input field with a regex pattern:

`<input type="text" maxlength="4" inputmode='numeric' pattern="\d*">`

I would like to use *javascript* to validate the input, by parsing the `pattern` attribute in some way like this (**which doesn't work**):

```
$('input').on('keypress', function(e){
    var regex = this.pattern,
        valid = eval(regex).test( e.charCode );

    if( !valid )
        return false;
});
```

I know the Regex in the pattern is different than the one JS uses, but I need some way to convert any Regex in a way this method could work, to allow the typing of only the chars allowed by the pattern.

Comment: As a rule of thumb : if your solution uses `eval`, it's probably bad.

Comment: I wouldn't say BAD if it's something I use internally for myself and no injection may occur.

Comment: Not "BAD" as is "prone to injection" but "bad" as in "inefficient, inelegant and prone to bugs".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor :

```
var regex = this.pattern,
    valid = new RegExp("^"+regex+"$").test( e.charCode );
```

But your pattern should probably be `\d+`, not `\d*`.

Comment: it's always `false` for me when i tried it...
`function testChar(pattern, s){
 return valid = new RegExp("^"+pattern+"$").test( s );
  
};

testChar("\d+", '3')`

Comment: That's because you badly create the string literal : use "\\d+" instead of "\d+". See http://jsfiddle.net/QK96C/

Answer (score 1):

Just add the start and end of the string `"^"+your reg ex here+"$"`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [this](http://ericleads.com/h5validate/) plugin.
It emulated the html5 features when they are not available (older browsers).

Comment: i'm looking for a minimal solution to this, like a one-line thing